# Import CSV data into Google sheet by NAME using Google Script - error Sheet is not defined

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, import, gmail

Please help - I am trying to create a Google script where I can automatically have a csv file that is emailed to me every day be imported into a google sheet by name so that way I can write another script to have a different csv file from a different daily email be imported into the same active google sheet by a different name (i.e. have 2 different sheets by 2 different names in the same Google Active Sheet).

This is my code below but it gives me the ReferenceError: Sheet is not defined for line 8

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {

  var threads = GmailApp.search("Your Aesop Report is Ready (FC Employee Assignment & Demographic)"); // enter search criteria here
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // runs in the current active sheet
  var sheet1 = Sheet.getSheetByName('FC Employee Assignment & Demographic');
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats(); // clears target sheet
    sheet1.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
    GmailApp.markMessagesRead
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("Your Aesop Report is Ready (FC Employee Assignment & Demographic)");
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('FC Employee Assignment & Demographic');
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.copyBlob().getDataAsString(), ",");
  sheet1.clearContents().clearFormats(); 
  sheet1.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  GmailApp.markMessagesRead(threads[0].getMessages()[0]);
}
```

Comment: I just did and it still says ReferenceError: Sheet is not defined
importCSVFromGmail @ Code.gs:6

Comment: Try it again. Please